# I'm trying to write a function in MIPS, int mash(int x, int y): Parameters x and y are passed in the stack

Tags: assembly, mips

Returns the value of 10*x + y in a register. Eg, max(8, 9) returns 89.
I have this and whenever I run it, it gives me 2147481597 for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

```
.text

   li $a0, 8  
   li $a1, 9  
   jal mash  
   
   addi $a0, $v0, 0   
   li $v0, 1
   syscall
   
   li $v0, 10 
   syscall

  
   mash:
      mul $v0, $a0, 10   # result = 10*x
      add $v0, $v0, $a1  # result = 10*x + y
      jr $ra # return
```

Comment: The code you've posted works just fine for me in QtSpim (after adding a `main` label). You haven't stated which simulator you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You've written a very vague code.

after calling the jal function you should save it in some variable initialized under .data using the command below.

```
              sw $v0, answer
```

Not sure why you applied that addi function.

also for the Mash function, you can save the values in general purpose register first and then move them to $v0

Instead of directly loading value in $a0 and $a1, you can first save them in some variable and use them later on.

I've corrected the code for you.

```
         .data
         x:          .word 8
         y:          .word 9
         answer:     .word 0

        .text
        .globl main
        main:
                    lw $a0,x
                    lw $a1,y
                    jal mash
                    sw $v0,answer
        
                    lw $a0,answer
                    li $v0,1
                    syscall

                    li $v0,10
                    syscall
        .end main
                   
         mash:
                    li $v0,0
                    mul $t0, $a0, 10
                    add $t1, $t0, $a1
                    move $v0, $t1
                    jr $ra
        .end mash
```

Comment: `addi $a0, $v0, 0` copies the value of `$v0` to `$a0`. Although `ori` might be more common, or just `move` if you're ok with using pseudo-instructions. Those data section variables are unnecessary.